# lmer linear contrasts : Kenward Rogers or Satterthwaite DF and SE

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

In R, I am searching for a way to estimate confidence intervals for linear contrasts for `lmer` models that use either kenward-rogers or satterthwaite degrees of freedom and SE.

For example, I can compute a CI for a fixed effect parameter in a mixed model like SAS with R, using the t-value (with df from KR) and SE.

```
mod<-lmerTest::lmer(y~time1+treatment+time1:treatment+(1|PersonID),data=data)
lmerTest::summary(mod,ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
```

This output:

```
Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      49.0768     1.0435 56.4700  47.029  < 2e-16 ***
time1             5.8224     0.5963 48.0000   9.764 5.51e-13 ***
treatment         1.6819     1.4758 56.4700   1.140   0.2592    
time1:treatment   2.0425     0.8433 48.0000   2.422   0.0193 *
```

Allows a CI for time1 like:

```
5.8224+abs(qt(0.05/2, 48))*0.5963 #7.021342
5.8224-abs(qt(0.05/2, 48))*0.5963 #4.623458
```

I would like to do this same thing for a linear contrast of the fixed coefficients. This is the p-value but there is no SE output.

```
pbkrtest::KRmodcomp(mod,matrix(c(0,0,1,0),nrow = 1)) 

         stat     ndf     ddf F.scaling p.value
Ftest  1.2989  1.0000 56.4670         1  0.2592
```

**Is there anyway to get a SE or a CI from lmer linear contrasts that uses this type of df?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you have at least two options: using the `lsmeans` package, or doing it manually (using functions `vcovAdj.lmerMod` and `pbkrtest::get_Lb_ddf`). Personally, I go with the later if the contrast to be tested is not very "simple", because I find the syntax in `lsmeans` a bit complicated.

To exemplify, take the following model:

```
library(pbkrtest)
library(lme4)
library(nlme) # for the 'Orthodont' data

# 'age' is a numeric variable, while 'Sex' and 'Subject' are factors
model <- lmer(distance ~ age : Sex + (1 | Subject), data = Orthodont)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: distance ~ age:Sex + (1 | Subject)
…
Fixed Effects:
    (Intercept)    age:SexMale  age:SexFemale  
        16.7611         0.7555         0.5215
```

from which we would like to obtain stats on the difference between the coefficients for age in males and females (i.e., `age:SexMale - age:SexFemale`).

Using lsmeans:

```
library(lsmeans)
# Evaluate the contrast at a value of 'age' set to 1,
# so that the resulting value is equal to the regression coefficient
lsm = lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ age : Sex, at = list(age = 1))$contrast
```

produces:

```
contrast           estimate         SE    df t.ratio p.value
1,Male - 1,Female 0.2340135 0.06113276 42.64   3.828  0.0004
```

Alternatively, doing the calculation manually:

```
# Specify the contrasts: age:SexMale - age:SexFemale
# Must have the same order as the fixed effects in the model
K = c("(Intercept)" = 0, "age:SexMale" = 1, "age:SexFemale" = -1)

# Retrieve the adjusted variance-covariance matrix, to calculate the SE
V = pbkrtest::vcovAdj.lmerMod(model, 0)

# Point estimate, SE and df
point_est = sum(K * fixef(model))
SE = sqrt(sum(K * (V %*% K)))
df = pbkrtest::get_Lb_ddf(model, K)

alpha = 0.05 # significance level

# Calculate confidence interval for the difference between the 'age' coefficients for males and females
Delta_age_CI = point_est + SE * qt(c(0.5 * alpha, 1 - 0.5 * alpha), df)
```

will result in a point estimate equal to `0.2340135`, SE `0.06113276`, df `42.63844`, and confidence interval `[0.1106973, 0.3573297]`

Comment: What a fantastic response! Thank you very much - very clear! I did receive word from one of the authors of lmerTest that they are looking at adding the ability to estimate contrasts in their next release.

Comment: Interesting that you find the seven statements for your manual calculation simpler than the one with lsmeans. In fact, if you use age as a by variable, it's even simpler: `lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ Sex | age)`